Is there a specific word/phrase for when you recognise a location from a film/TV/the News?
I'm thinking about the eerie feeling you get when you go to a place and you recognise that it was once plastered all over the news because a serious crime was committed there - or if a serious crime has happened in your neighbourhood and it's now plastered on the news. Or if a crime drama is filmed in your neighbourhood. I'm specifically thinking about crime but it could be a word that covers a more general meaning. A compound word or phrase is acceptable.
Word searches I've tried: deja vu; set jetting; recognise
Example sentence:

I got off the train and felt [word].



Is there a specific word/phrase for when you recognise a location from a film/TV/the News?

No, there is not.

Isn't that a bit presumptuous? I mean there may be a word for it, you never know.

No, not really presumptuous at all. Would you argue that there is possibly a word for "to hit a brick made of compressed sawdust with a left-handed hockey stick?" Note that the question precludes illustrations in books and paintings or indeed seeing such a place in real life.

This is how words get made

@LRG Of course, but words appear in response to a need... I had hoped that ""to hit a brick made of compressed sawdust with a left-handed hockey stick?" might convey that to ordinary people.

Yes, there’s dé·​jà vu, adopted from the French, meaning “already seen.”
The experience is the same, whether or not you’ve actually seen it before.

OP mentions déjà vu in their question!

déjà vu doesn't mean that in English. It means that you feel you recognise something, but probably haven't. It's illusory.

@WeatherVane That’s what the poster is asking about—an illusory event, the impression that you’ve already seen something.

@KateBunting Not mentioned in the original question.

Second paragraph: "Word searches I've tried: deja vu; set jetting; recognise".

Oh, perhaps they did; it’s still the answer that fits. Posters often use the very words that suit their queries best.

Deja vu isn't quite right - although the feeling is similar. I want a word that specifically relates to having seen the crime scene on TV. Whereas, Deja vu is a sense you've been there before.

Not a single word, but "a sense of familiarity"  would cover it, or if that were compressed to a single word:
I got off the train and felt "home".

The quote marks indicate that it's not home as in the place we live; rather its an allusion to everything meant and implied by being at home.
I imagine walking into a movie/TV set that you watched a lot would inspire a similar feeling, as would visiting a youtube-personality that you watch a lot, like Big Clive or similar.

The point is that it's not familiar. It's somewhere you recognise but it's not how you recognise it. I asked a friend and she said 'defamiliarisation' which I think is more the feeling I'm after but would love for it to have some connection to the screen. Alas, I don't think the word exists.
